# invalid read on pointer returned from get()

Tags: c++, c++14, unique-ptr

New to C++ and trying to understand object lifetimes and smart pointers.

Why does the result of creating a raw pointer from a unique_ptr with get() in this fashion:

```
auto w = (std::make_unique<Wall>()).get();
```

result in a pointer that passes a null check but causes an invalid read when used (and according to valgrind looks like caused by a double delete in the Wall destructor?) but when created in a two step fashion:

```
auto wall = std::make_unique<Wall>();
auto w = wall.get();
```

present no such problems?

So I have two questions:

(1) why does the first way result in a raw pointer causing an invalid read and the second way doesn't?

(2) why does the invalid read pointer pass a null check?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

class Object {
public:
    virtual ~Object() = 0;
    virtual void talk() {}
};

Object::~Object() {}

class Wall: public Object {
public:
    virtual ~Wall() {}
    virtual void talk() { std::cout << "I'm a wall." << std::endl; }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    //auto wall = std::make_unique<Wall>();
    //auto w = str.get();  
    auto w = (std::make_unique<Wall>()).get();

    if (!w) 
        std::cout << "null pointer..." << std::endl;

    w->talk();
}
```

valgrind output:

```
    ==21668== Memcheck, a memory error detector
    ==21668== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
    ==21668== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
    ==21668== Command: ./wall
    ==21668== 
    ==21668== Invalid read of size 8
    ==21668==    at 0x402452: main (main.cpp:33)
    ==21668==  Address 0x5ab6c80 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 8 free'd
    ==21668==    at 0x4C2F24B: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
    ==21668==    by 0x402548: Wall::~Wall() (main.cpp:15)
    ==21668==    by 0x402955: std::default_delete<Wall>::operator()(Wall*) const (unique_ptr.h:76)
    ==21668==    by 0x40269C: std::unique_ptr<Wall, std::default_delete<Wall> >::~unique_ptr() (unique_ptr.h:236)
    ==21668==    by 0x40242A: main (main.cpp:27)
    ==21668==  Block was alloc'd at
    ==21668==    at 0x4C2E0EF: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
    ==21668==    by 0x4025CD: _ZSt11make_uniqueI4WallIEENSt9_MakeUniqIT_E15__single_objectEDpOT0_ (unique_ptr.h:765)
    ==21668==    by 0x40240E: main (main.cpp:27)
```

Comment: What do you think happens when the `unique_ptr` gets destructed?

Comment: *Why* are you extracting the raw pointer in the first place?

Comment: Why do you need this? What's wrong with `auto w = new Wall();`?

Comment: I wanted to use extracting a raw pointer from a unique_ptr as a way of using a managed pointer and passing it around without using move.

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux mostly it lacks a guaranteed and defined owner.

Comment: "I wanted to use extracting a raw pointer from a unique_ptr as a way of using a managed pointer and passing it around without using move." well thats not how it works. When you extract it, its not "managed" anymore. If you don't want to move, pass by const reference, or use a shared_ptr.

Answer (score 9):

In

```
auto w = (std::make_unique<Wall>()).get();
```

the anonymous `std::make_unique<Wall>()` only exists until the end of the line. Then it goes out of scope and is destroyed, taking the contained pointer with it.

This deletes the pointer out from under `w` without `w` being aware. `w` passes the null check because it is not null, but where it points must not be used.

In your second example

```
auto wall = std::make_unique<Wall>();
auto w = wall.get();
```

`wall` maintains the `unique_ptr` until `wall` goes out of scope, which is hopefully long enough to make use of `w`.

My suggestion is to discard `w` and use `wall` throughout. This way there is no chance for a dangling pointer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

class Object {
public:
    virtual ~Object() = 0;
    virtual void talk() {}
};

Object::~Object() {}

class Wall: public Object {
public:
    virtual ~Wall() {}
    virtual void talk() { std::cout << "I'm a wall." << std::endl; }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    auto wall = std::make_unique<Wall>();

    if (!wall)
        std::cout << "null pointer..." << std::endl;

    wall->talk();
    wall.reset();
    if (!wall)
        std::cout << "null pointer..." << std::endl;
}
```

Expected output:

```
I'm a wall.
null pointer...
```

Comment: And that's why it passes the null check... because it does point to an address but that address is now invalid, yes?

Comment: You got it. Updating answer.

Comment: `wall.release();` leaks. Use `wall = nullptr;` instead (or `wall.reset();`)

Comment: @milleniumbug <expletive deleted>! Thanks! Totally wrong function.